# getRandomValues() in Node: "expected Uint8Array"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cryptography

I'm trying to use the getRandomValues() function for an encryption REST API I'm making for practice. I'm using Node for the server. Because of this, I know that I do not have a window object which also contains the crypto object that usually contains the "getRandomValues()" function.

Whenever I test it, I get this error: `TypeError: expected Uint8Array`

This error happens at the 3rd line in this function:

```
getrand: function (places) {
  var array = new Uint32Array(20);
  getRandomValues(array);

  var ret = array[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < array.size; i++) {
    ret *= array[i];
  }

  ret = this.shiftnum(ret, 10);
  return ret;
},
```

Also, up above I have imported the npm package with `var getRandomValues = require('get-random-values);`

I have looked at the documentation for the package, as well as seen some stackoverflow answers where someone gives an example of using the package. The code snippet example directly from the [package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-random-values) is here:

```
var getRandomValues = require('get-random-values');

var array = new Uint32Array(10);
getRandomValues(array);
// => [ 
// =>   183, 
// =>   76, 
// =>   18, 
// =>   177, 
// =>   73, 
// =>   9, 
// =>   50, 
// =>   248, 
// =>   216, 
// =>   104 
// => ]
```

This is also the same format I've seen in examples. I have also tried making a very simple test function to debug this issue as follows:

```
test: function() {
  var array = new Uint32Array(10);
  getRandomValues(array);
  console.log(array[0]);
  return;
}
```

The exact same issue happens on the third line. In addition, I have tried changing the `var array = new Uint32Array(10);` line to `var array = new Uint8Array(10);` just to humour the error, but the error remains exactly the same.

Basically, I'm trying to figure out why this wont work. I've been messing with this for a couple days and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the error of my own ways:

> getRandomValues(buf)
>   Fills integer-based TypedArray buf with cryptographically random
>   numbers. Checks for and uses the first of the following:
>
> window.crypto.getRandomValues
>
> window.msCrypto.getRandomValues
>
> Node.js crypto
>
> If none of the above are available, then an Error is thrown.
>
> Throws QuotaExceededError if buf.length > 65536 (even if Node.js
>   crypto, which doesn't have that limit, is being used).
>
> buf must be a Uint8Array if Node.js crypto is used, otherwise a
>   TypeError will be thrown.

Apparently I was using Node.js crypto, therefore I needed a Uint8Array. I don't know what happened before, but after changing my code this time it worked.

Answer (score 3):

The package is intended to work on a browser or on node through `require('crypto').randomBytes`, since you only want it to work on node you could work with the function `randomBytes` on your own

```
var crypto = require('crypto') 
var array = crypto.randomBytes(10).toJSON().data
console.log(array)
// [ 233, 217, 45, 204, 150, 171, 160, 70, 18, 138 ]
```

Note that `randomBytes` return a buffer